# IgniteRDD SQL Table Names

Tags: sql, apache-spark, caching, rdd, ignite

When using the .sql method on IgniteRDDs, I need to have the "table" name to do the WHERE clause. I don't know how to retrieve it, and the example provides the name Integer for an [Int, Int] type cache. I have tried recreating it with [String, Int] caches etc. but haven't been able to figure out how they got that Integer name.

Does it have to do with Spark naming conventions, or is it a part of Ignite? 
It seems a simple issue, but I just can't find the RDD's table name.

Their example can be viewed here: https://github.com/apache/ignite/blob/master/examples/src/main/spark/org/apache/ignite/examples/spark/SharedRDDExample.java

Config file: https://github.com/apache/ignite/blob/master/examples/config/spark/example-shared-rdd.xml

Answer (score 2):

In configuration you can find:

```
  <property name="indexedTypes">
    <list>
      <value>java.lang.Integer</value>
      <value>java.lang.Integer</value>
    </list>
 </property>
```

this is a list key(odd) and value(even) types which would be indexed. more details you can find here: https://apacheignite-sql.readme.io/docs/schema-and-indexes#section-registering-indexed-types

The table has a name of value type, in this case, it's "Integer".